# Prevent enter button form submission if email input is on focus (jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some forms set up so that they are submitted by clicking the enter key. The problem is that some people tab to fields and then use their arrow keys and enter to select an item from their form input history.

So currently I have:

```
$(document).keyup(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    if ($("#signin").is(":visible")) {
        document.getElementById('LoginAction').click();// clicks the login button
     } else if ($("#createaccount").is(":visible")) {
         document.getElementById('newUserAction').click();// clicks the new user button
     }
    }
 });
```

and I want to make sure that if they are focused on an input that it doesn't launch the page until they are on blur to all the inputs.

Answer (score 2):

Only override it for the email field:

```
$("#emailField").keypress(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```